# kivymd adding widgets to the current screen real-time

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am currently developing a chat application using kivymd using sockets of course and have the main server and the client code. The problem comes when I receive the message from the server from say client x and me being in the chat screen I want to display the chatbuble with the received message. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
@mainthread
    def incoming_message(self, msg):
        print(f"Incoming called ::{msg}")
        source, receiver = "francis","anita"

        chats[receiver].append(f'{msg};2:20pm;read;friend')
        # Adding the typed text to chat screen
        self.chatmsg = ChatBubble()
        self.chatmsg.msg = msg
        self.chatmsg.time = "2:00 pm"
        self.chatmsg.isRead = "read"
        self.chatmsg.sender = "you"
        wm.screens[4].ids['msglist'].add_widget(self.chatmsg)
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: I have something that might help you but we need sufficient information to be able to help